# Mongodb timeout while using for loop

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to insert 100k documents to a collection.After inserting some 300-400 documents getting error like failed to execute script.I think it is because of timeout.If it is timeout or any how can i resolve this.

I am using below code in robo3T.

```
var user=db.getCollection('User').findOne({"user_Email" : "anandkumar@yahoo.com"});


    for (i = 1; i <= 100000; i=i+1){ 

         user._id=user._id+i;

        db.getCollection('User2').insert(user);

    }
```

ERROR:

[image]

Comment: what is you connection string there should be connection timeout or SocketTimeout setting ..

Comment: @sandeeprawat i didn't get you

Comment: How you are connection db ..

Comment: @sandeeprawat i am not sure its beacuse of timeout

Comment: where are executing the query ..

Comment: @sandeeprawat In robo3T

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185807/discussion-between-nithin-and-sandeep-rawat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

robo3T  connection have advance tab check for below setting

- Max. connection idle time
- Server selection timeout
- Socket timeout
- Connect timeout

Comment: shell timeout is there so i increased from 15 seconds to 300 seconds.Still same issue occuring.

Comment: You can get help https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/ranking

Comment: i have updated error screenshot in question.please check

Comment: It is issue with connect time out setting   3ms *500 = 15  sec ... so your time out is not set  restart robo3T Clint ..

Comment: i will check it.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo will automatically assign an `_id`, but it is an object, and can't be incremented like that.

This code will have a better chance of working:

```
var user=db.getCollection('User').findOne({"user_Email" : "anandkumar@yahoo.com"});


    for (i = 1; i <= 5000; i++){ 

         user.seq = ((user.seq) ? user.seq : 0) + i;

        db.getCollection('User2').insert(user);

    }
```

Not really sure what you are trying to achieve though :)

Comment: user varaible contains _id also.If we try to insert 5000 documents.1st document will insert normally.From 2nd onwards _id will be duplicate.